# Real-life applications of non-uniformly charged line charge and ring of charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

The title sums it up; are there any practical examples of not uniformly charged line charges and ring of charge?
Line chargers: I know they are used in wire chambers for high-energy physics experiments, but usually, they are uniformly charged from what I've read. Connected wire to the battery are chargeless, so I'm kind of clueless now.

Thank you:)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why should there be? since on a conductor it will be uniform. So The only thing I could think of is a plastic rod you rub to do some experiments in electro static.